# How to count the number of values in a column then divide by row totals

Tags: r, count

I have a dataset that has 6 rows and one column. The column contains the number 2 or 3. What i would like to do is count the number of times the 2 occurs and the 3 occurs then divide by the number of rows.

For example there are two 2s in the column so 2/6 = 33%.

I have used `table(df['over1.5'])` to count the number of occurrences but not sure how to do divide the counts by the total number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `proportions` on the `table` output

```
round(100 *proportions(table(df$over1.5)))

 2  3 
33 67
```

---

Or with `count` and divide by the `sum` of frequencies

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  count(over1.5) %>% 
  mutate(percentile = round(100*n/sum(n)))
  over1.5 n percentile
1       2 2         33
2       3 4         67
```

#### data

```
 df <- data.frame(over1.5 = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3))
```

Comment: proportions worked great, thank you.